# perl chdir not working, not changing the directory

Tags: perl

My complete perl script is

```
chdir ("/etc" or die "cannot change: $!\n");
print  "\nCurrent Directory is $ENV{PWD} \n";
```

and I am getting output (not as expected)

```
bash-3.2$ perl test.pl
```

Current Directory is `/home`

P.S. `/home` is where I am executing the `test.pl`

Comment: Drop the parentheses and that should work. Don't use them unless lines get cluttered.

Answer (score 12):

1. You should move `or die` outside of `chdir(...)`, i.e.:

   ```
   chdir("/etc") or die "cannot change: $!\n";
   ```

   With what you have currently, the expression `"/etc" or die "cannot change: $!\n"` is evaluated first. 
   Its result is `"/etc"` and `die()` never gets executed. `or die()` should be "applied to" `chdir()` call, not to its argument.
2. Do `print(cwd);` to print current working directory. Don't forget to `use Cwd;`

---

```
use Cwd;

chdir("/etc") or die "cannot change: $!\n";
print(cwd);
```

Answer (score 5):

[Alex Shesterov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2170192/alex-shesterov) has given the right answer, but since this has some interesting details, I will elaborate. Here is [the documentation for `or`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-or-and-Exclusive-Or):

> Binary "or" returns the logical disjunction of the two surrounding
>   expressions. It's equivalent to || except for the very low precedence.
>   This makes it useful for control flow:
>
> ```
> print FH $data    or die "Can't write to FH: $!";
> ```
>
> **This means that it short-circuits: the right expression is evaluated
>   only if the left expression is false.**

What the Perl documentation writer meant by "This means that", I guess we'll never know, but the following part of the sentence is important: **It short-circuits**.

In Perl, "true" and "false" are handled somewhat conveniently, in that there are only a few false values, and all other values are considered true. For example, `undef`, `0`, the empty string and the empty list are examples of "false" values. And a string such as the one in this question `"/etc"` can never be false.

When passing arguments to a function/subroutine, lists are used. A list is a series of independent statements, such as:

```
"foo", "bar", "baz"  # three strings, foo bar baz
qw(foo bar baz)      # same thing
my @array = qw(foo bar baz);
@array;              # same thing, unless scalar context
```

However, the `or` operator does not create a list, rather it forces the statement to be evaluated right away, before it is passed to the function. So, this is what happens:

```
chdir ("/etc" or die "cannot change: $!\n");
#      ^^^^^^-- true value
--> "/etc" or die ? --> "/etc"
chdir("/etc");
```

You have found a new version of this classic mistake. Usually this is what people do:

```
open my $fh, "<", "file" || die "Cannot open: $!";
```

Which is the same mistake, in a more subtle version: The logical or `||` operator has [higher precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) than the comma operator, which makes the above statement similar to:

```
open my $fh, "<", ( "file" || die "Cannot open: $!" );
```

Which is exactly the problem you ran into: The `die` statement can never logically be executed, since a string with a file name can never (unless it is empty, or zero) be false.

Answer (score 1):

This code work as you expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Cwd qw(chdir);

chdir ("/etc") or die "cannot change: $!\n";
print  "\nCurrent Directory is $ENV{PWD} \n";
```